# Remove margin in android toolbar icon

Tags: android, android-toolbar, margins

I get this weird margin in my app toolbar between icon and navigation icon in the toolbar (as in the image).
I've got no idea about where it comes from and how to remove it. After searching the internet I found this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

But I still get this margin as in the figure:
[image: Margin]

**Edit >> Solution**

Well after using layout bound I figured much of the margins are of the icon(as in figure). But can I still remove this margin and change the size of the icon and the title text.
[image]

**Edit**

Following @Amir solution:
Helper for java:

```
class BasicActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    protected Toolbar mToolbar;    /// Initilize it in onCreate methode
    .....

     protected void setupToolbar(String title) {
        toolbar=(Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        if (ab != null) {
            ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

       if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(title)) {
        setTitle(title);
    }
}

}
```

And in your activity class:

```
class Main extends BasicActivity{
     @override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle saved){
          super.onCreate(saved);
          ....
          setupToolbar("MAIN");
     }
}
```

Comment: set **contentInsetStart** to zero in your toolbar.

Comment: contentInsetStart | contentInsetLeft | contentInsetEnd | contentInsetRight

Comment: i've already done that....

Comment: So easiest way is to turn on Layout bound and you can find out it's related to your home icon or drawer Icon.

Comment: plz see the edit.. and plz suggest a answer

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can easily remove **Margin | padding** between title and back icon with:

```
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

**Margin | padding** In left/right side of toolbar with:

```
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

Also if you need more customization do with following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/color_primary"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_toolbar_left"
            style="@style/IconFont.Large"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground" />



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_toolbar_title"
            style="@style/Textview.White.MediumSmall"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/icon_toolbar_right"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon_toolbar_left"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/nav_category"/>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_toolbar_right"
            style="@style/IconFont.Large"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: only one more question will it support the option menus?

Comment: @ASK yes it's also supported.

Comment: well i got it but I've got one more problem now if I want to set title and icons i'll have to declare functions per activity can you give me a way out of that too.( maybe how to create a custom toolbar view extending the toolbar)

Comment: @ASK Create a BaseActivity that extend your Activity and put **setToolbarTitle** , **setToolbarIcon** and other kinds of method inside. then you just need to pass your title and icons :)

Comment: I've edited my question with a solution from your approach. Plz check  to see if I'm in the right track or plz edit the mistakes

Answer (score 7):

You can adjust the margins by modifying the theme and style, like this：

```
<style name="cusToolbarNavigationButtonStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation">
    <!--default is 56dp-->
    <item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>  
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">16dp</item>
</style>

<style name="cusToolbarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <!--default 4dp-->
    <item name="titleMargin">0dp</item> 
    <!--default @dimen/abc_action_bar_content_inset_with_nav-->
    <item name="contentInsetStartWithNavigation">0dp</item> 
</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="toolbarNavigationButtonStyle">@style/cusToolbarNavigationButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/cusToolbarStyle</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using this

```
   <android.widget.Toolbar>
    android:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
</android.widget.Toolbar>
```

if using

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the margin/padding from the title in a CollapsingToolbarLayout you might find this usefull:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
    app:expandedTitleMarginStart="0dp"
    .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:contentInsetEndWithActions="0dp"
            >
```