# How to remove padding from title in toolbar?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

My Toolbar

[image: My toolbar]

Google Play Toolbar

[image: GooglePlay toolbar]

How can I remove unnecessary padding?

My toolbar is inside the fragment
My code in fragment:

```
public void setUpToolbar(Toolbar toolbar, String title, @DrawableRes int resId) {
    toolbar.setTitle(title);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ActionBar ab = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setHomeAsUpIndicator(resId);
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

My toolbar in xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38302389/1462770

Comment: app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"

Answer (score 44):

**Use this inside your toolbar xml tag**

```
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

Answer (score 19):

Just add in your toolbar

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
```

It should work

Answer (score 4):

Had this problem recently, and even after setting all the `insets` to `0dp` there was still a gap between the NavigationIcon and the Title. Apparently this is the Margin of the TitleView, and to remove this we have to set `app:titleMarginStart="0dp"`.

So on the whole, had to do the below to remove the entire gap.

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
app:titleMarginStart="0dp"
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this in your code:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_action_bar, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) customView.getParent();
parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to add app:contentInsetLeft:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
```