# Set app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation on ActionBar programmatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, androidx, android-actionbar-compat

I have upgraded an older Android app to androidx.

Now there is a big space before the icon in the Actionbar.

[image]

I was looking into it and found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38301115/remove-margin-in-android-toolbar-icon) where it explains that it is due to

```
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation
```

and

```
app:contentInsetStart
```

I**s there a way to set them both to 0dp programmatically?**

My code at the moment:

```
public static void initializeActionBar(Context context, ActionBar bar, boolean showBackButton){
    if (bar != null) {
        bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.wood2));
        bar.setIcon(R.drawable.icon_white); //custom logo
        if(showBackButton){
            bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

This code is used in various activities like this:

```
ActivityTools.initializeActionBar(this,getSupportActionBar(), false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use  Toolbar for this

First, use a  Toolbar

then you can use [**`setContentInsetStartWithNavigation(int insetStartWithNavigation)`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setContentInsetStartWithNavigation(int))

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
class DemoActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recurring_billing)

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar)

        mToolbar!!.setContentInsetsAbsolute(10, 0)
        mToolbar!!.contentInsetStartWithNavigation =10



    }
}
```